# Doubt about exercise: Finding basis of an ideal of $O_K$ (Ring of algebraic integers)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Given $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (This part was edited), the exercise is to find a basis for $I=\langle 5+\sqrt{2},7+2\sqrt{2}\rangle$.

This is what I did:

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\{(a+b\sqrt{2})(5+\sqrt{2})+(c+d\sqrt{2})(7+2\sqrt{2}): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
&=
\{(5a+2b+c7+4d)+(a+5b+2c+7d)\sqrt{2}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align*}$$

This is $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}=O_K$

Suppose you want $H+J\sqrt{2}$, with $H,J \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Picking $d=0,a=-5b-2c$, and by Bezout I can pick $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+2b+7c=-25b-10c+2b-7c=-23c-17c=H$ (since $17$ and $-23$ are primes), then $a$ is clearly an integer.

So the basis I can pick is $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ and done.

Now it seems rather odd, that it just happened to be $O_K$, have I done something wrong? .

Comment: Hint: $I$ contains the gcd of the norms of the generators.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: An ideal that contains $1$ contains all of $\mathcal{O}_K$... so what you did is absolutely wrong; what you gave is a pair of elements such that the ideal they generate contains $I$, not one that is equal to $I$.

Comment: (Assuming you meant $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$) I do not see how you concluded that $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ is a basis from what you did. But in fact this ideal is equal to $O_K$, since $1 = 33\sqrt{2}(5+\sqrt{2})+(5-25\sqrt{2})(7+2\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: I just realized i wrote $K=\mathbb{\sqrt{5}}$ instead of $\sqrt{2}$, its supposed to be $\sqrt{2}$, juts fixed it. Well, the definition of basis of an Ideal $I$ of $O_K$ I have been working on, is a set of $n$ elements, ($n$ the degree of $K$) such that any elemento of $I$, can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of those elements with interger coefficients. Hence $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ must be the basis.